# Can php eval return a boolean value?

Tags: php, eval

I cant seem to get eval to return a boolean value for '(4 > 5)'

Is this possible? If not how might I get this to work (without writing a parser)

I have tried this:

```
$v = eval('return (10 > 5)');
var_dump($v);

// Result = bool(false)
```

UPDATE

Thanks to @Pekka - I added a semicolon to the above code and it works.

Comment: Be careful with the `eval` statement.

Comment: @mhitza - doesn't work, see update to post above

Comment: @You - yes. very very careful :)

Comment: It works if you add a semicolon to the end of the statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the manual](http://www.php.net/eval):

> eval() returns NULL unless return is called in the evaluated code, in which case **the value passed to return is returned**. If there is a parse error in the evaluated code, eval() returns FALSE and execution of the following code continues normally. It is not possible to catch a parse error in eval() using set_error_handler().

It'll work like @mhitza already said in the comment. I would just add brackets to be safe:

```
    $x = eval('return (4 < 5);');
    echo $x;
```

Comment: Yup - I forgot the semicolon - CHEERS!

Answer (score 1):

This has probably already been answered sufficiently...but what helps me is to always think of the eval in PHP as the entire line of code, and don't forget the semi-colon, e.g.

```
eval('\$myBooleanValue = 4 > 5;');
return $myBooleanValue;
```

Don't try stuff like this:

```
$myBooleanValue = eval('4 > 5');
```

Comment: Yup - JavaScript's `eval()` can do the latter, but not PHP's.

Comment: Is your code still valid if `$myBooleanValue` has not been defined before the `eval()` statement? I have such a case in my code.

Comment: @KanwarbirSingh, yes...I don't know of any quirks that would prohibit it from working like any other line of code.  Since you can write `$myBooleanValue = 4 > 5` to initiate a variable, you can do the same thing inside an eval()

Answer (score 1):

Please enable `display_errors` & a suitable `error_reporting` before turning to the community:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in -(2) : eval()'d code on line 1

Aha:

```
eval('return (10 > 5);');
```

Notice the `;`.

Comment: If you did, you should've included it in your question. But for now: `unexpected $end` is always either a missing `;`, or unclosed `{` or `(`, so you can recognize it in future :)