# php calculate formula in string

Tags: php, formula, equation

So I have formula  as string

`$comm = "(a x 5% - 2%)";`

I want it to be  `$comm = $a * 5/100 * (1-2/100);`

How can I do this in php?

Comment: Probably, you'll need to write parser.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2695-PHP-Safely-evaluate-mathematical-expressions.html

Which can evaluate Math Code

```
 // instantiate a new EvalMath
  $m = new EvalMath;
  $m->suppress_errors = true;
 // set the value of x
  $m->evaluate('x = 3');
   var_dump($m->evaluate('y = (x > 5)'));
```

Found at:
[Process mathematical equations in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019418/process-mathematical-equations-in-php)

Comment: hi Duk i am getting an error `Exception: Class 'EvalMath' not found` how can i use this classs

Comment: Good one without reinventing the wheel!

Answer (score 3):

To do this the right way, reliably and safely, from scratch, you will need to perform:

1. Lexical analysis, this involves pattern matching the input with tokens:

   ```
   (a x 5% - 2%)
   ```

   would become something like the following chain of tokens:

   ```
   openparen variable multiply integer percent minus integer percent closeparen
   ```
2. Syntax analysis, this involves taking those tokens and defining the relationships between them, something like this, matching up the patterns of tokens:

   ```
   statement = operand operator statement
   ```
3. Then you will need to parse the resulting syntax tree so that you can run it and produce the answer.

It won't ever look as simple as `$comm = $a * 5/100 - 2/100;` but it will result in the same conclusion.

Someone somewhere has already likely had a go at this problem, here's two I found after a brief Google search:
[PHP Maths Expression Parser](http://codehackit.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/expression-parser-in-php.html),
[And another](http://route50.net/forum/thread/2196).

These SO questions are similar as well [Smart design of a math parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114586/smart-design-of-a-math-parser), [Process mathematical equations in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019418/process-mathematical-equations-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

It just trying, but maybe good start.

```
$somm = 0;
$a = 30;

$str = "(a x 5% - 2%)";

$pt1 = "/x/i";
$str = preg_replace($pt1, "*", $str);

$pt2 = "/([a-z])+/i";
$str = preg_replace($pt2, "\$$0", $str);

$pt3 = "/([0-9])+%/";
$str = preg_replace($pt3, "($0/100)", $str);

$pt4 = "/%/";
$str = preg_replace($pt4, "", $str);

$e = "\$comm = $str;";
eval($e);
echo $e . "<br>";
echo $comm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

```
<?php 
    function evalmath($equation)
    {
        $result = 0;
        // sanitize imput
        $equation = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9+\-.*\/()%]/","",$equation);
        // convert alphabet to $variabel 
        $equation = preg_replace("/([a-z])+/i", "\$$0", $equation); 
        // convert percentages to decimal
        $equation = preg_replace("/([+-])([0-9]{1})(%)/","*(1\$1.0\$2)",$equation);
        $equation = preg_replace("/([+-])([0-9]+)(%)/","*(1\$1.\$2)",$equation);
        $equation = preg_replace("/([0-9]{1})(%)/",".0\$1",$equation);
        $equation = preg_replace("/([0-9]+)(%)/",".\$1",$equation);
        /*if ( $equation != "" ){
            $result = @eval("return " . $equation . ";" );
        }
        if ($result == null) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to calculate equation");
        }
        return $result;*/
        return $equation;
    }
    $total = 18000;
    $equation =  evalmath('total-(230000*5%-2%+3000*2*1)');
    if ( $equation != "" ){

        $result = @eval("return " . $equation . ";" );
    }
    if ($result == null) {

        throw new Exception("Unable to calculate equation");
    }
    echo $result;
?>
```