# Math operation directly from form value

Tags: php, forms, function

I wanted the math operation to be done directly from the form post value. Is there a function to accomplish this? I tried this, but it just echo's out the input value as it is:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="equation" value="2+(3+4)">
<input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>

 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['equation'])){
   $equation = htmlspecialchars($_POST['equation']);
 echo $equation;
}
?>
```

As you see, i like to get the output of 2+(3+4) while echo the $equation.

Comment: Why would you do it that way?

Comment: You have to build your own function. If you want to do direct math, build it in your PHP or get user input then assign it to variables and do the math from there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [calculate math expression from a string using eval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880772/calculate-math-expression-from-a-string-using-eval)

Comment: possible duplicate of [php calculate formula in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999578/php-calculate-formula-in-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$equation = preg_replace('[^0-9\+-\*\/\(\) ]', '', $_POST['equation']);
if(!empty($equation)){
   eval( '$total = (' . $equation . ');' );
   echo $total;
}
```

You have to take care about the security or use preg_replace and/or put some conditions.

Comment: Ram you're awesome bro. Thanks :) I'll take care of the security . But thanks a lot for the method.. amazing..

Answer (score 1):

Usually people use eval for this purpose, but it's better not to use eval, it is not a good pratice, it's a big hole in security.

```
function calc($str)
{
    $str = preg_replace('[^0-9\+-\*\/\(\) ]', '', $str); 

    $compute = create_function('', 'return (' . $str . ');' );
    return 0 + $compute();
}

echo calc($_POST['equation']);
```

Comment: C'mon, @plutov.by, a little explanation won't hurt! ;)