# PHP - Need to calculate the string formula to integer value

Tags: php, string, function

I need to convert the formula like string to its calculated value, in PHP.

For eg:

```
$str = "(20000+(2000*(40/100)))*(10/100)";
$calculated_value = ????; // Calculated value of the above string "$str".
```

I need to calculate value of the string "$str" and store it in separate string.
Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If someone suggests using a function starting with an `e` and ending on `al`, then ignore that. You need to parse this string (possibly using a stack-based approach). Fun!

Comment: Take a look at @ircmaxell's answer to this previous version of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692727/how-to-make-a-calculator-in-php - it's the best PHP answer you'll find

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2695-PHP-Safely-evaluate-mathematical-expressions.html

And [Process mathematical equations in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019418/process-mathematical-equations-in-php)