# How to avoid using eval for a particular string of variables that needs to be executed

Tags: php, eval

I have things like this using `eval()`:

```
$result = eval("return ".$value1.$operator.$value2.";");
```

Where the operator is from a variable, or a db field.

How would I go about achieving the same result without using `eval`? Is it possible?

It's not a security concern as the values/operator aren't user entered, but it may be a performance concern if [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php#82239) at the PHP manual is anything to go by. Plus, if at some point I want to try out Facebook's HipHop I need to replace all uses of `eval` with something else.

Comment: You might want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015242

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(strcmp($operator, "+") == 0) {  
  return   $value1 + $value2;
}  
else if(strcmp($operator, "*") == 0) {  
return   $value1 * $value2;  
}  
...
```

As @Gumbo mentioned, you can also use `switch()`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure about operators, but you can do something like this with function names:

```
function add($x, $y) {
    return $x + $y;
}

$value1 = 1;
$value2 = 2;
$func = "add";

$result = $func($value1, $value2);
```

You can even do this with builtin functions:

```
$func = 'array_sum';
$result = $func(array($value1, $value2));
```