# Calculate a sum in a string

Tags: php

I have string like this: `$string = "a + b + c";`. Now I would like to calculate the string as sum.

For example:

```
$a = 10;
$b = 10;
$c = 10;
$string = "a + b + c";

echo "Result is ".$string;
output-> Result is 30

$string = "a + b * c";

echo "Result is ".$string;
output-> Result is 110
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables in your string are missing the dollar signs. I wrote and tested a script for you that adds these signs to the variables and then parses the string as PHP code using the function `eval()`.

```
$a = 10;
$b = 10;
$c = 10;
$string = "a + b + c";

$result = eval('return ' . preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9])+/', '\$$1', $string) . ';');
echo $result;
```

This will output `30`.

Comment: You can use `return` in eval statements.

Comment: @Michiel Pater is it possible with `$string = "a+b+c";` then in code  `eval('return ' . preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9])+/', '\$$1', $string));`

Comment: @user559744: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: @Michiel Pater working great. why you add `;` at end of the string?

Comment: @user559744: Nice, that was a mistake. I have updated the code.

Comment: @Michiel Pater can you help me again? I changed the string format `$string = "aa + ba + cx";` and your code does not support that string format. thanks any ways

Comment: It should be `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` instead of `([a-zA-Z0-9])+`

Answer (score 3):

I once made a [calculator script](https://github.com/Sjord/calculator/blob/master/calculator.php).

- It parses the calculation and puts each number and operator on a stack, in [reverse polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).
- It calculates the results by executing operations all operations on the stack.

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen that doesn't use eval(). Could use an update though, a few of the examples didn't work.  Worked fine for most equations though.

Answer (score 3):

Your question may already have been answered here on StackOverflow:

[How to evaluate formula passed as string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015242/how-to-evaluate-formula-passed-as-string-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

My standard answer to this question whenever it crops up:

Don't use eval (especially as you're stating that this is user input) or reinvent the wheel by writing your own formula parser.

Take a look at the [evalMath](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2695-PHP-Safely-evaluate-mathematical-expressions.html) class on PHPClasses. It should do everything that you're asking, in a safe sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
$string = "$res = $a + $b + $c;";
eval($string)
echo($res);
```