# Perform calculation inside php string

Tags: php, string, numbers

I have a string like

```
$str = "23 + %%val%%";
```

Now, if I wanted to perform this calculation giving `%%val%%` a value, e.g. 20, how could I do?

Comment: `$str = "" . (23 + $val);`

Comment: 23 is in the $str togheter with $val :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to keep this format, you can do this :

```
function calculate($string, $value) {
  return str_replace('%%val%%', $value, $string);
}

$str = "23 + %%val%%";
$value = 25;
$result = eval('return '.calculate($str, $value).';');

var_dump($result); // int(48)

$result = eval('return '.calculate("16 + %%val%%", 10).';');

var_dump($result); // int(26)
```

But be careful with eval (See : [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php))

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. PHP isn't recursively executable, unless you use `eval()` (**DON'T** use  `eval()`). Why can't you just do

```
$str = 23 + $val;
```

?

Comment: Because 23 is inside $str :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = 10;
$b = 10;
$c = 10;
$string = "a + b + c";

$result = eval('return ' . preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9])+/', '\$$1', $string) . ';');
echo $result;
```

this will echo 30.

there is another post about this here [Calculate a sum in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337525/calculate-a-sum-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "23 + {$value}"
```

Then to perform the calculation, you'd need a function that takes a string and breaks up the integers and operators. Seems like a waste since php is not strongly typed, and you can easily convert strings to integers.