# how to parse str in variable

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to parse following text in variable...

```
$str = 3,283,518(10,569 / 2,173)
```

And i am using following code to get `3,283,518`

```
    $arr = explode('(',$str);
    $num = str_replace(',','',$arr[0]); //prints 3283518
```

the above $str is dynamic and sometimes it could be only 3,283,518(means w/o ()) so explode function will throw an error so what is the best way to get this value? thanks.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803679/parse-math-operations-with-php

Comment: I think the OP is just want to get the string before `(`, nothing involve math

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = "3,283,518(10,569 / 2,173)";

preg_match("/[0-9,]+/", $str, $res);
$match = str_replace(",", "", array_pop($res));

print $match;
```

This will return 3283518, simply by taking the first part of the string `$str` that only consists of numbers and commas. This would also work for just `3,283,518` or `3,283,518*10,569`, etc.

Comment: @seoppc That would take you less than a minute to test. But yes, it would.

Answer (score 0):

Probably going to need more information from you about how dynamic $str really is but if its just between those values you could probably do the following

```
if (strpos($str, '(' ) !== false) {
     $arr = explode('(',$str);
     $num = str_replace(',','',$arr[0]);
} else {
     //who knows what you want to do here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really sure about number format, you can try something like:
`^([0-9]+,)*([0-9]+)`
Use it with preg_match for example.
But if it is not a simple format, you should go with an arithmetic expressions parser.

Answer (score 0):

Analog solution:

```
    <?php

$str = '3,283,518(10,569 / 2,173)';

if (strstr($str, '('))
{
    $arr = explode('(',$str);
    $num = str_replace(',','',$arr[0]);
}
else
{
    $num = str_replace(',','',$str);
}

    echo $num;

?>
```