# input values with operators in a form

Tags: php, forms, operators

I want to allow users to insert values in a form with operators, ​​as in this example.

```
60*24
```

I need to know what is the most appropriate way to process this in php

Comment: show us what have you tried

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803679/parse-math-operations-with-php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function for that

Something like this once you submit form

```
echo eval($_POST['yourtextfieldname']);
```

Comment: **NOTICE:** input _must_ be properly checked in this case, because of code injection possibility. It is a simlest way, but **not safest one**.