# PHP: how to input binary operators + - * / % in a form?

Tags: php, user-input, discrete-mathematics

I have written a basic HTML/PHP to calculate the [Cayley table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table) of some also basic binary operations over a finite set with *n* elements.

The filename is `q.php` and the code (cleaned of all styles, etc.) is the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;"></head>
<body>
<form action="q.php" method="post">
    Order:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="c1"><br><br>
    Operation:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="c2"><br>
    (syntax:<strong>&nbsp;$i "+" $j "%" 3&nbsp;</strong>)<br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate / Reset">
</form>
<?php
$n=$_POST['c1']; $p=$_POST['c2'];
echo "<table style=\"text-align: center; margin: auto;\" cellpadding=\"8\">\n";
for ($i=0; $i<$n; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    for ($j=0; $j<$n; $j++) {
        eval("\$a=\"$p\";");
        echo "\t<td>".$a."</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

It is very easy to input the integer `n` in the form, but (exactly as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417870/input-values-with-operators-in-a-form)) I can't find a good way to input in the form the binary operators (are they strings?).

More precisely, if the operation on *i* and *j* is e.g. *i+(j mod 3)*, I would like to input sometinhg like

```
i + j % 3
```

or even

```
$i + $j % 3
```

instead of

```
$i "+" $j "%" 3
```

This latter with double quotes - not really enjoyable for the user - works already.

Can we do something better? And maybe also manage brackets `()`, to calculate `(i+j)*2` as easily as `i+(j*2)` that I already do?

I'm now curious, thank you!

Comment: I think you're looking for [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://htmlspecialchars).

Comment: You had better really trust your users if you're going to `eval()` arbitrary data entered on a web form.

Comment: @AmalMurali: are you sure this is the same? Doesn't it convert -e.g.- % to &#37; ?

Comment: @MattAllegro: Watch what happens if you type `print_r(phpinfo(),true)` into your input box. Check out [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015242/how-to-evaluate-formula-passed-as-string-in-php) for some possible solutions.

Comment: If you want to print the result of your post data you can use this `eval("\$a= {$p};"); echo "\t<td>" . $p . " = " . $a . "</td>\n";` in your code in the replacement of your eval code.

Comment: @gildonei: indeed, that's what I was tuning now. (Why) did you delete the answer? It solves the task. Tomorrow I'll also check the link to the SO question in comment by cpilko, but this one of you runs smooth!

Comment: @MattAllegro sorry for post delete I didn't understand your question properly, so i thought I had posted a wrong answer. Undeleting post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$n = $_POST['c1']; 
$p = trim(str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['c2'])); // Remove spaces


eval("\$result = {$p};");
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: It works with nested brackets and covers a set of easy examples, as expected, very good!

Comment: if you watch my syntax and yours, the only difference is that you put braces in `\$result = {$p};` ...but this made the difference!