# Storing value got from function eval in php variable

Tags: php

```
eval("echo {$row11['incentive']};");
```

In my table column named incentive , I have values stored like a string  for eg. `'($workshop_sales*0.005)'` and there are mutliple kind of formula stored for calculation of incentive.

I have result generated using above code in php  but when I am going to store its value in any variable then it is not getting stored.

How can I store its result? is it possible or not ??

Comment: be careful, eval() is evil!

Comment: Agreed, always check what you are evaluating.
In your case you can use `return` instead of `echo`. It will return the evaluated value and you can assign it to your variable. `$foo = eval("return {$row11['incentive']};"); `

Comment: horrible programming. don't use eval. if you need to compute a value, use a function and `return` the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of *echoing* inside the *eval-ed* code, *return* the value:

```
<?php
$workshop_sales = rand(1000, 9999);

$row11['incentive'] = '($workshop_sales*0.005)';

$result = eval("return {$row11['incentive']};");

var_dump($result);
```

---

From the [docs](https://php.net/manual/function.eval.php#refsect1-function.eval-returnvalues):

> eval() returns NULL unless return is called in the evaluated code, ...

---

And obvious *eval is dangerous*-statement (also from the docs):

> **Caution** The **eval()** language construct is very dangerous because it
>   allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged.
>   If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to
>   use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user
>   provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Comment: Thank you very much . That is the thing which I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption:

```
$workshop_sales = 15;
$row11['incentive'] = '($workshop_sales*0.005)';
```

- **Variant 1** Saving result directly (**unsecure**):

  ```
  $foo = eval("return {$row11['incentive']};");
  echo $foo; //Outputs 0.075
  ```
- **Variant 2** Replace variable before (should be [**pretty secure**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803679/parse-math-operations-with-php))

  ```
  function do_maths($expression) {
      eval('$o = ' . preg_replace('/[^0-9\+\-\*\/\(\)\.]/', '', $expression) . ';');
      return $o;
  }

  //Replace Variable with value before
  $pure = str_replace("\$workshop_sales", $workshop_sales, $row11['incentive']);
  //$pure is now (15*0.005)

  //Interpret $pure
  $foo = do_maths($pure);
  echo $foo; // Outputs 0.075
  ```

But be careful with `eval()`, it is **evil**.

Further information on [When is eval evil in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php)

> The main problems with eval() are:
>
> **Potential unsafe input**. Passing an untrusted parameter is a way to fail. It is often not a trivial task to make sure that a parameter (or part of it) is fully trusted.
>
> **Trickiness**. Using eval() makes code clever, therefore more difficult to follow. To quote Brian Kernighan "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it"

Answer (score 0):

simply you can assign the variable to the new value inside the `eval` function

and use your variable later

for example :

```
eval('$result = "2";');

echo $result;
```

this will print out the value of the `$result` variable

PS, 
you have to take a look at what @yoshi had mentioned about the dangerous of using eval