# Store plus and minus in a variable PHP

Tags: php

How can I solve this problem:

```
if ($variable == 1) {
    $math = "-";
} else {
    $math = "+";
}

$numberOne = 10;
$numberTwo = 10;

$result = $numberOne $math $numberTwo;
```

This doesn´t work, is there any way to solve this?

Comment: You cannot just put variables in a row and expect them to be evaluated as PHP expression.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015242/how-to-evaluate-formula-passed-as-string-in-php. Ought to be helpful if you plan on supporting other operations.

Comment: @Gazler's answer works, but what you're trying to do here suggests something of a misunderstanding of how PHP interprets statements (you're assuming it will concatenate the values of three variables and then correctly evaluate them as a mathematical statement). Is there a more-basic question we can answer about why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will work for your example.  A subtraction is the same as adding a negative.  This will be far safer than the alternative of using [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

```
if ($variable == 1) {
    $modifier = -1;
} else {
    $modifier = 1;
}

$numberOne = 10;
$numberTwo = 10;

$result = $numberOne + ($numberTwo * $modifier);
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could use [**`eval()`**](http://www.php.net/eval) -- but that would be quite a bad idea *(it would not be good for performances, it's not "clean", ...)*

In this kind of situation, I would generally go with a `switch` on the operator, and one case per possible operator.

Here, it would mean using something like this :

```
switch ($math) {
    case '+':
        $result = $numberOne + $numberTwo;
        break;
    case '-':
        $result = $numberOne - $numberTwo;
        break;
}
```

Which can easily be extends to other operators.

*(In your specific situation, if you only have `+` and `-`, though, some calculation based on a multiplication by `+1` or `-1` would be faster to write)*

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($variable == 1) {
    $math = -1; // subtraction
} else {
    $math = 1; // addition
}

$numberOne = 10;
$numberTwo = 10;

$result = $numberOne + ($math * $numberTwo);
```

Answer (score 1):

No love for the ternary operator? 

To minify [Gazler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768468/store-plus-and-minus-in-a-variable-php/6768489#6768489) a bit further:

```
$modifier = ($variable == 1) : -1 ? 1;

$numberOne = 10;
$numberTwo = 10;

$result = $numberOne + ($numberTwo*$modifier);
```

Comment: I think most people avoid answers using the ternary operator unless the code provided uses it for clarity reasons.  There is absolutely nothing wrong with it though, and I would use it if I was using my own solution.

Comment: minify hell: `$result = $numberOne + ($numberTwo * (($variable == 1) : -1 ? 1) );`

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use more complex mathematics, you can use the [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval) function.