# Is it possible to POST a fractional number from a form?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the inverse of the number thats POSTED from a form.

```
<select name="inverse_num">
<option value="2">2 </option>
<option value="1">1 </option>
<option value="1/2">1/2 </option>
<option value="1/3">1/3 </option>
</select>
```

In the php file which gets the value, say "1/2",

```
$my_inverse=1/($_POST[inverse_num]);  // returns 1 , but..
$my_inverse=1/(1/2);  // returns 2, which is required.
```

Why does this happen..coz logically I'm posting the same value. Please suggest.

Comment: Your value is posted as text, not numbers.

Comment: What if you add a `(1*$_POST['inverse_num'])`?

Comment: There is also a PHP class available to do this. Might be useful if your maths gets a little more complicated at any stage. More about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015242/how-to-evaluate-formula-passed-as-string-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can only post text from a form.
- PHP doesn't care if a variable contains a string or a number, it will convert between them.
- **PHP won't resolve text that looks like equations.**

You could do something along the lines of:

```
function simple_fractions ($value) {
    if (is_numeric($value)) {
            return $value;
    }
    preg_match('/^(\d+)\/(\d+)$/', $value, $matches);
    if ($matches[1] && $matches[2]) {
            return $matches[0] / $matches[1];
    }
    if ($matches[1] == 0) {
            return 0;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your two expressions:

```
$my_inverse=1/($_POST[inverse_num]);   // array keys shall be quoted
$my_inverse=1/(1/2);
```

Are actually:

```
$my_inverse=1/"1/2"; 
$my_inverse=1/(1/2);
```

Which does explain the outcome.

If you were to send the string `0.5` instead, then PHP would process it as expected, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Quentin has a possible solution.

However, another one is even better in my opinion:

```
<select name="inverse_num">
<option value="a">2 </option>
<option value="b">1 </option>
<option value="c">1/2 </option>
<option value="d">1/3 </option>
</select>
```

Then in your submission script:

```
if($_POST['inverse_num'] == 'a'){
  $value = 2;
}elseif($_POST['inverse_num'] == 'b'){
  $value = 1;
}elseif($_POST['inverse_num'] == 'c'){
  $value = 1/2;
}elseif($_POST['inverse_num'] == 'd'){
  $value = 1/3;
}
```

Etc....

Nothing complex about this method.

Comment: Assuming that the values are always the same, or at most modified from this code...

Comment: @ChaimChaikin - his code is using static HTML with drop down boxes... aka they are the only options.  That's why this is such an easy solution...  The above one works though.

Comment: True, sometimes though, people only post the static HTML even if the code is generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

What about posting decimals instead of fractions? 
e.g. 0.5