# Fetch the real value from string variable PHP

Tags: php, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to evaluate formula passed as string in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015242/how-to-evaluate-formula-passed-as-string-in-php)

I have a string like "10*0.1+800"  I would like to get the actual answer of the this string in numeric instead of the string value.

I have tried `floatval` php function but had no luck. Any idea?

Comment: DON'T use `eval`, even though a lot of people are suggesting it!

Comment: @x3ro Then What is the Best method to do this thanks for your comments

Comment: Look at the linked "duplicate question". The accepted answer features a full blown math expression parser that does not introduce the security risk of eval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to "evaluate" the string using the eval function of PHP:

```
eval('return ' . $string . ';');
```

But i would really only do this, if you can trust the string. Because what you are doing here is indeed executing PHP code. It's a possible security hole, if you can't trust the string.

The other possible option would be to use a parser. I am sure, there are already any libraries for this task available.

Comment: "But i would really only do this, if you can trust the string" - I can't imagine a situation where you would want to eval an arbitrary string, even if you think you can trust it, there may always be a bug that allows insertion of random strings.

Comment: @x3ro: but than again: you can have bugs everywhere and "stop programming" is not really an option, either ... isn't it?

Comment: No, but you shouldn't use eval if it is not absolutely necessary, and there are plenty of math expression parsers out there that don't use eval, are there not?

Comment: @x3ro: yes, and i mentioned this, too. but sometimes a real parser is just overkill ... if you can trust the string ;-).

Comment: @harald: I strongly disagree. Especially given the fact that you don't have to write the parser yourself, there is no upside in using `eval` (except for performance, but then again, you're coding in PHP) and the security risk it introduces is just not proportional to any benefit you might have. The problem is that, by suggesting `eval` here, newbie programmers reading this question will probably adopt the use of eval without reflecting, which I think is really, really bad.

Comment: @x3o: that's the reason why i wrote about the possible security hole in the answer. in my opinion a newbie programmer should make his own mind about what could be a possible security hole. and imo writing safe applications starts at some other points like trusting / validating data coming into your program from whatever source ... but this is no course about secure programming -- imo.

Answer (score 1):

You could try :

```
$string = "10*0.1+800";
$result = eval("return "+$string);
```

but beware of the security risks of using eval !

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function of php which will evaluate the string.

```
$str = "10*0.1+800"
eval('return ' . $str. ';');
```