# PHP: I have a string that has a mathematical operation in it. How do I run it?

Tags: php, math

(Please note, it's been user entered, so I cannot hard code it). Anyways, the user enters math.php?do=2+2 and the script will kick back 4 as a result. Another thing is that the input is rigorously verified, so, there is no malicious possibility. My testing method is this

```
function testMath($char){
    $array['math'] = Array("+", "-", "/", "*", "(", ")", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");
    foreach($char as $chr){
        if(!in_array($chr, $array['math'){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Would it be safe to eval() something checked by this? or should I forget about doing math from user-entered input?

Side note, PHP throws

```
Parse error: parse error in C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\App\html\new.php(24) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

When I try to eval() something. What's wrong?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do the math on the user's end with javascript? way less risky

Comment: `eval` has some obvious safety problems if it's done on user input .. your test seems okay, but you may want to limit the length as well.  What does it look like when you call `eval`?

Comment: Or use something that's already been created: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015242/how-to-evaluate-formula-passed-as-string-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you used the eval() since you didn't post that part of your code. But if you are going to eval the code, you need to specify the variable it will be saved to:

Revised testMath:

```
function testMath($char){
    if(strlen($char) > 10) return false;
    $array['math'] = Array("+", "-", "/", "*", "(", ")", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");
    foreach($char as $chr){
        if(!in_array($chr, $array['math'){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

$math = $_GET['do'];
if(testMath($math)) eval("$result = " . $math . ";");

echo $math, ' = ', $result;
```

Comment: `$sanitizedUserInput` requires hella sanitization.

Comment: the testMath() function provided above, could possible be sufficient... i would add a character limit on it as tandu mentioned earlier.

Comment: Well, I would execute it in a way that would look similar to your if(testMath(...