# doing math with a string

Tags: php, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP String Calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499778/php-string-calculation)

I am trying to make a 24-game solver.

Can i do something like this?:

```
$x = '*';
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

$sum = $a $x $b; //Trying something like this
$sum = $a * $b; //Actual sum

if($sum == $result) echo 'Hello World!';
```

Or $x as an array.

It's so confusing.

Comment: fyi, a "sum" is only when you add two numbers. If you multiply two numbers, it's a "product." Or just "the result."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to do that?

Why not:

```
$x = '*';
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

$sum1 = $x == '*' ? $a * b : false;
$sum2 = $a * $b;

if($sum1 == $sum2) echo 'Hello World!';
```

That'll have the same effect, without trying to eval a string.

Comment: thanks can use a switch, stupid me ;p

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) which lets you execute a php string. Read the CAUTION section on that page though: do not to pass any user provided data into it.