# Differentiate between mathematical user input and all else

Tags: php, math, machine-learning, nlp

How can I use machine-learning or some other technique to differentiate between what is mathematical user input and what is not mathematical user input in PHP?

By mathematical user input, I mean a mathematical statement that can be computed / solved.

So, I built a calculator that can handle basic arithmetic in PHP.
Before, I pass the user input I want to check if it is a mathematical statement that can be computed. And if it is not then `echo "can not be computed";`

So in pseudo code / semi-code:

```
function isComputable($input){
    /* code I need help with here */
}
$userInput = $_GET['input'];
if(isComputable($userInput){
    compute($userInput);
}
else{
    echo "can not be computed";
}
```

What is the best way to do this in PHP?

Comment: I'm not clear about your problem. Do you have problem with expression validation?

Comment: @MuhammedHedayet Currently I am just using a regex that looks for number, whitespace, mathematical operator, number. I feel that is too specific. I am looking for something broader that that.

Comment: well then I think [Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) will serve what you're looking for :)

Comment: @MuhammedHedayet Looks great. Do you know of any PHP implementations? If so, please link and post an answer so I can select it as right.

Comment: @DjangoJohnson, you still need some lexical analysis. Unfortunately Regular expressions [will not quite get you there](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/parsing-beyond-regex.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) is a nice one to solve this problem. You can find many implementations of Shunting-yard algorithm in PHP online. It only takes a stack and a queue data structure to check whether an expression is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the OP has already built the calculator. He does not want to evaluate an expression, he just wants to know if a given string is a mathematical expression or not. Why not try a machine learning approach? You can train a classifier with a few examples of acceptable mathematical expressions.

You can use an online API like [Wit](http://wit.ai) to try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The *quickest* way to do a little PHP (or JavaScript, for that matter) "calculator" of the type you describe would be to

1. Validate the input to make sure the ONLY characters that it contains are decimal digits, parentheses, and the symbols `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`, then
2. Pass that string to the evil `eval` function.

You'll either get a result or a problem.  Of course, using `eval` is known to be dangerous and most people wouldn't use it (see the [WARNING](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) in the docs!)  In this case one could probably make the argument that "at least if I ensure that there are only digits, parens, and operators there, then I guess eval will be safe."

However, you'd be wise not to even take the chance, though.  You should define a little grammar of arithmetic expressions, then use a parser to validate the string and do the evaluation.  This isn't a trivial amount of code, but [someone has already done this on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1015242/) -- so adopt that code for your calculator.

The advantage of rolling your own evaluator (besides not having to explain to your friends that you used `eval` :) ) is that you can add your own operators, and perhaps even do some nice tricks with arbitrary precision math.  It's not something that takes only five minutes, but it is a useful exercise.