# Calculate math expression from a string using PHP

Tags: php

How do I calculate a math expression in the form of a string to an output using PHP?

```
<?php
    $ma ="min(2+10,5*1,max(8/2,8-2,abs(-10)))"; // math expression
    print $ma; // output of the calculation
?>
```

Comment: You could use [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), but mind you, this comes with serious security issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to evaluate formula passed as string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015242/how-to-evaluate-formula-passed-as-string-in-php)

Comment: In this question `eval` is probably the right answer, however this does feel like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question

Answer (score 6):

I made a `math_eval` helper function package that should do exactly want you need.

Example usage:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$two   = math_eval('1 + 1');
$three = math_eval('5 - 2');
$ten   = math_eval('2 * 5');
$four  = math_eval('8 / 2');
```

Link: https://github.com/langleyfoxall/math_eval

In the background, this wraps around the mossadal/math-parser package.

Comment: While this package appears to be good, it’s licenced under LGPL so it will never get the usage it deserves. If it’s not MIT, commercial applications won’t use it.

Comment: Be aware that the example code on the github page misses the mandatory `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`

Answer (score 1):

I've found some parsers on GitHub, this one looks very interesting:

[mossadal/math-parser: PHP parser for mathematical expressions](https://github.com/mossadal/math-parser)

It can be used this way:

```
use MathParser\StdMathParser;
use MathParser\Interpreting\Evaluator;

$parser = new StdMathParser();

// Generate an abstract syntax tree
$AST = $parser->parse('1+2');

// Do something with the AST, e.g. evaluate the expression:
$evaluator = new Evaluator();

$value = $AST->accept($evaluator);
echo $value;
```

It  can also be used with functions like `cos()` or `sin()`.